# Find the one-time users in a system- sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 6 columns- Date, time, action, user_id, channel, and time_and_date.
Action refers to open or close, when a user starts or end watching a tv channel.

My tasks are as following
to get an overview of the data:

```
- find the one-time users (who used the service only once or in only one day and 
never came back) for each channel, each genre, each community
```

Anoother table provides the user_id, genre(news, sport....)

How can I find the one time users for those requirements?

Comment: Please provide the DDL statements for the involved tables.

Comment: Is a user who was in different channels/genres/communities considered a one-time user or not?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds something like this:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from action_table
where action = 'open'
group by user_id
having count(*) = 1
order by user_id
```

Comment: well I tests all examples given, but non of them runs correctly. I will try to refine my question... 
 1. table has the columns- Date, time, action, user_id, channel, and time_and_date. Action refers to open or close, when a user starts or end watching a tv channel.
2. table has- channel and genre 

First I try to look for the users in first table that watch a channel not more then one time in total OR just MAX one time a day.
Second to find the users that watch a channel JUST one time in total or for each GENRE.

I hope the question is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

`SELECT FROM first_table LEFT JOIN users ON first_table.user_id=users.id GROUP BY users.id HAVING COUNT(users.id)=1`

You can join your genre table after for selecting over genre channels...

Answer (score 0):

To get the one-time users:

```
select user_id ,min(channel) as channel, min(genre) as genre, min(community) as community
from action_table
group by user_id
having min(date) = max(date);
```

Note the `having` clause.  This guarantees that a users has only one date (but not necessarily one record).

This returns one value for each of the three dimensions -- for a one-time user they are the same.  For someone who visits multiple times in one day, it chooses one value.